# virtual machines automatic deployment and provisioning

Tags: deployment, vagrant, build-automation, provisioning

In the recent times, I tend to set-up and configure more and more VMs daily with very similar or the very same configuration, and due to the time consumption caused by that, I'm looking for a way to automate the whole process.

I have started looking around and I have found Vagrant which could be a very good starting point.

I would like to create a custom build of a VMWare VM ( vagrant box if not mistaken ), and I would like to use that box as my base and deploy it on my servers.

The trouble starts here:
On my servers I use VMWare vSphere and I see that Vagrant can support it via an external plugin, but, as I read along, I see that vSphere only supports VMs created from template or cloned from an existing one.

Is there any change to run my VMWare Workstation boxes with it ?

Also, I would be very grateful if you could provide me with some more info on the same matter using other ( maybe better suited ) solutions.

I know there are also Chef and Puppet, but are they maybe an *overkill* for my needs ?
Thank you for your time and help,
Best regards.

Comment: Might I suggest that this question would be better asked at http://serverfault.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Ansible? http://www.ansible.com/home

There is an opensource one available it is *extremly* easy to use. Might be what you're looking for.